# BackgroundTask UWP C++ trigger only one time?

Tags: c++, uwp, background-task

In windows runtime component project (BackgroundTask c++)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "BackgroundTask.h"
using namespace Platform;
namespace SyncBackground {
    void BackgroundTask::Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance^ taskInstance) {
        _taskInstance = taskInstance;
        taskInstance->Canceled += ref new BackgroundTaskCanceledEventHandler(this, &BackgroundTask::OnCanceled);
        _deferral = taskInstance->GetDeferral();
        OutputDebugString(L"Debug: CPP\r\n");
    }
    void BackgroundTask::OnCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance^ sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason) {
        _deferral->Complete();
    }
}
```

I try `ApplicationTrigger` from c# project, but `OutputDebugString` write only one times from first trigger. In the same BackgroundTask C#, `Debug.WriteLine()` write every trigger.

Then why in c++ do it only one times? And how make it work look like c# (i need send some data and command via trigger)
Thank

Comment: Do you mean you use c# project to call the c++/cx component? If the OutputDebugString write only one time from first trigger, does the BackgroundTask::Run method trigger every time? This is an [official sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask/cpp) with c++/cx, when I added OutputDebugString in it, it could output everytime, you can check it.

Comment: That sample can trigger again when last trigger call `TaskDeferral->Complete();` (tested). But in c# BackgroundTask i'm not call it and still work every trigger (i need it still run background). When call `TaskDeferral->Complete();` background process will exit when UI app closed.

Answer (score 0):

> I need it still run background

If I understand correctly, you just want to run background tasks indefinitely. If so, even if you don't call `TaskDeferral.Complete();`, it won't still run background, after a period of time, it will still be terminated. In that case, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly#run-background-tasks-indefinitely) to configure. But it mentions if you use it, you can't put an app into the Microsoft Store. If not, please point me out.

Comment: Yes. But it can't get any trigger again if not call `TaskDeferral.Complete()`

Comment: I can't reproduce in c# background task. When I used the BackgroundTask C# to test without `TaskDeferral.Complete();`, it can only trigger one time from first trigger, the behavior is the same as c++, how did you let it trigger every time?

Comment: I'm drop this cx, background task not good. So i try cpp winrt to run as nomal program and packing as uwp for some api.

Comment: So when you use cpp/winrt, can it work as expected?

Comment: Got example, it work. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CloudMirror